# Convert hexadecimal number to its equivalent emosy Unicode char in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, unicode

I have hexadecimal code of all emosy. Now i want convert it to its equivalent emosy char in javascript.

I have done same in **java** like this-

```
int hax =0x1F600;
String unicodeChar = String.valueOf(Character.toChars(hax));
```

I have tried `String.fromCharCode` in **javascript** like this but no luck please help

```
var hax =0x1F600;
var unicodeChar = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hax , 16))
```

Comment: Finally i found solution as emosy are two charectores
var getUnicodeChars = function (value) {
    var output = '';
    if (value > 0xFFFF) {
        value -= 0x10000;
        output += String.fromCharCode(value >>> 10 & 0x3FF | 0xD800);
        value = 0xDC00 | value & 0x3FF;
    }
    output += String.fromCharCode(value);
    return output;
};
var unicodeChar = getUnicodeChars (0x1F600);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be lucky when ES6 is out. There is a [draft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint), which specifies the brand new `String.fromCodePoint` method, providing the functionality you requested.

Until ES6, you might want to copy-paste polyfill from the page I linked above. It gives you (in chrome console):

```
▶ String.fromCodePoint(0x1F600) 
// ⇨ ""
```

Comment: Thanks mudasobwa for reply. This is working fine. I have already found solution which in my comments also works well.
https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js/blob/master/punycode.js

Comment: There might be over 9000 different solutions, this one is in my opinion the correct one, since it’s standard-compliant and everything you’ll need to update when ES6 is released is to remove your `es6-preliminary.js` file (or whatever it’s called.) The rest of your code will be ready to ES6, which is a great advantage.